# How to create controlls script in Unity 4.6?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can i make control script for Unity3D 4.6 ? Like rotating element with mouse and moving it with keyboard.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? User input, rotation, movement? If all then i would study the Unity Documentation.

Comment: I have problem with rotation. Because in 4.6 i cant get it how to make my script works.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you use uGUI.

In the case, you should control rotation of RectTransform.

```
this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rotation
```